# Laravel 8 left join where clause is ambiguous

Tags: laravel-8

I'm trying to use leftJoin but I'm having problem with conflicts between equal names in both tables.

Tables

```
products:  added_by - user_id - published - approved - featured
product_types: added_by - user_id - published - approved - featured
```

> ```
>     $products = ProductType::
>     leftJoin('products', 'products.product_type_id', '=', 'product_types.id')
>     ->select('product_types.*')
> ```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by implementing the correct relationships, it will help you in the future.

```
class ProductType extends Model {
    public function products(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    // Add the other missing relations too (user, etc)
}

class Product extends Model {
    public function productType(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductType::class);
    }

    // Add the other missing relations too (user, etc)
}
```

You can now use:

```
// Query all Product Types with related products
$productTypes = ProductType::with('products')->get();

// Query all ProductTypes that have products
$productTypes = ProductType::withWhereHas('products')->get();

/** @var ProductType $productType */
foreach ($productTypes as $productType) {
    // You have access to the collection of associated products, in memory
    $productType->products;
}
```

More information on eloquent relationships in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships